# How could humans defeat or survive a creature that adapts every time it dies?

Tags: aliens

So if a carnivorous creature that comes back to life every time it dies arrived on Earth, how would humans defeat or survive it?

- there is only one specimen of this creature
- every time it dies it adapts (e.g. it gets killed by drowning; it now has gills)
- the creature is a little bit smarter then an average gorilla

Comment: by not killing it, restraining it, simple :/

Comment: and by making sure it doesn't die so it doesn't become stronger

Comment: This would be the greatest thing ever for humans, no need to defeat this creature. Kill it by placing it in plasma 10k °C hot and see how it adapts. Put immense pressure on it and see how it adapts. Let it die of thirst or hunger and see how it adapts. Only an insane man would want to permanently kill the greatest thing to ever happen to the human race

Comment: @Raditz_35 i didnt think about that! it would be even better if humans could control it and train it to obey, and study its body and learn from that creature!

Comment: @nefas or maybe let it die of hunger and thirst, so it can adapt and we dont need to spend resources to keep it alive

Comment: Launch it into space and dump it into vacuum. Let it survive only by solving puzzles so each iteration is more intelligent than the last. Unfortunately a question that generates a list like the one this already has can only be classed as opinion based.

Comment: @Separatrix an infinitly intelligent space dragon at our disposal? That's the goddamn best idea I've ever heard here.

Comment: @Fl.pf. " at our disposal"? Wouldn't it be angry, you know, after we killed it so many times?

Comment: @Mołot kill it with hate a couple times so it only knows love

Comment: Please see https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4317/what-to-do-about-unstoppable-questions

Comment: @Raditz I regret that I have but one upvote to give!

Comment: Show it 4chan and it will kill itself rather than continue to exist among us.

Comment: ...somehow, I don't think that's what death means.  And if it can adapt, it would be much better served by adapting while alive than after it's dead.